# Displaying java list content using JSTL per table row

Tags: java, html, jstl

I'm having trouble with displaying data in an html table using java jstl. I'm hoping someone has done this before and can offer guidance or an example.

This is how the table(rows, data) is currently displaying :

```
Apple, Orange, Mange
100, 101, 102
200, 201, 202
300, 301, 302
```

But this is how I actually need it to display

```
Apple, 100, 200, 300
Orange, 101, 201, 301
Mango, 102, 202, 302
```

This is my current JSTL display code

```
<c:forEach items="${dataSetList}" var="currentDataSetObj">
    <tr>
     <c:forEach items="${currentDataSetObj.myList}" var="currentValueOfDataElement" varStatus="loopCount" >
          <td>  <c:out value="${currentValueOfDataElement}" />  </td>
     </c:forEach>
     </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

And this is the server code

```
public class DataSet {
    List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
    // more stuff not relevant to question here
}

List<DataSet> dataSetList = new ArrayList<DataSet>();
DataSet dataSetOne   = new DataSet();
DataSet dataSetTwo   = new DataSet();
DataSet dataSetThree = new DataSet();
DataSet dataSetFour  = new DataSet();

List<String> fruitA = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> priceA = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> priceB = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> priceC = new ArrayList<String>();

fruitA.add("Apple");
fruitA.add("Orange");
fruitA.add("Mango");
priceA.add("100");
priceA.add("101");
priceA.add("102");
priceB.add("200");
priceB.add("201");
priceB.add("202");
priceC.add("300");
priceC.add("301");
priceC.add("302");

dataSetOne.setMyList(fruitA);
dataSetTwo.setMyList(priceA);
dataSetThree.setMyList(priceB);
dataSetFour.setMyList(priceC);

dataSetList.add(dataSetOne);
dataSetList.add(dataSetTwo);
dataSetList.add(dataSetThree);
dataSetList.add(dataSetFour);

request.setAttribute("dataSetList", dataSetList);
```

Answer (score 2):

the easiest way to do it is changing the value's order inside dataSet.

for example:

```
fruitA.add("Apple");
fruitA.add("100");
fruitA.add("200");
fruitA.add("300");
```

Answer (score 2):

@ZaoTaoBao has [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23113209/1066779) your question,

---

Apart from your problem:

make your server code simple follow **OO** design in Java.

instead of creating many `List's` , create a class to hold fruit information like:

```
public class Fruit {
    private String name;
    private double[] prices;        
        //getters, setters & constructor 
}
```

then create one `List` object to hold `Fruit's` like:

```
List<Fruit> fruitList = new ArrayList<Fruit>();

Fruit appleFruit = new Fruit("Apple", new double[]{100.0, 200.0, 300.0});
Fruit orangeFruit = new Fruit("Orange",new double[]{101.0, 201.0, 301.0});
Fruit mangoFruit = new Fruit("Mango",new double[]{102.0, 202.0, 302.0});

fruitList.add(appleFruit);
fruitList.add(orangeFruit);
fruitList.add(mangoFruit);

request.setAttribute("fruitList", fruitList);
```

and render Fruits in jsp using single `<c:forEach..`

```
<c:forEach items="${fruitList}" var="currentFruit">
    <tr>      
       <td> 
        <c:out value="${currentFruit.name}" />        
       </td>       
        <c:forEach items="${currentFruit.prices}" var="price">
            <td>
                ${price}
            </td>
        </c:forEach>       
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
```

**See Also**:
[Object Oriented Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_design)